# How to Double a number using service in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing an application in which i want to double a number using service call in angularjs but its not working...

Below is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-controlller="myCrtl">
                <input ng-model='num'>  {{double(num)}}
            </div>
                <script>
                    var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);

                    app.service('abc',function(){
                        this.myFun=function(value){
                            return value * 2
                        }
                    });

                    app.controller('myCrtl',['$scope','abc',function($scope,abc){
                        $scope.double=abc.myFun(num);
                    }])
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you have a typo in here. `<div ng-controlller="myCrtl">` should be two `ng-controller`

And since the double is a function you need to treat is as scope function

```
$scope.double= function(){
       return abc.myFun($scope.num);
 }
```

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller('myCrtl',['$scope','abc',function($scope,abc){
      debugger
      $scope.num = 0;

      $scope.double = function() {
          return abc.myFun($scope.num);
      }
  }])
  app.service('abc',function() {
      this.myFun = function(value) {
          return parseInt(value) * 2;
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="myCrtl">
        <input ng-model='num'>  {{double()}}
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question calls for a way to call a method of a `service`, I agree that [sachila ranawaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6428638/sachila-ranawaka)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452513/613302) is correct.

I would however expand the point by implementing it as a `filter` which may be simpler and cleaner if it's a somewhat trivial thing that might be used across the app:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.num = 0;
}]);

app.filter('double', function() {
    return function(value) {
        return parseInt(value, 10) * 2;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input ng-model="num">  {{ num | double }}
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{2*num}}` if you want to double the number. why do you go for complex things.

Comment: He wants to use a **service**, read the question. Maybe the finality is more complex than just doubling a number...